# Login OnClick Event not firing

Tags: asp.net

This is my first attempt at creating an asp.net website so please be kind. I'm attempting to fire a click event on a submit button in ASP.NET, the template I'm using has this html

```
<div id="lightbox"></div>   

<div id="loginbox-panel">
<a href="#" id="lightbox-close"></a>

        <form action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="frame">
                    <h4>TestSite</h4>
                    <small>Sign in to your account.</small>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="text" value="Username" class="input-text autoclear" />
                    <input type="password" value="Password" class="input-text autoclear" />
                </div>

                <div class="separator"></div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="input-submit float-right" />
                    <a href="#" class="float-left">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

</div>
```

I believe the `input type="submit"` is client side but could be made to run a server side event using

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="input-submit float-right" 
runat="server" 
onserverclick="LoginButton_Click"/>
```

with code behind

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //login handler
}
```

However, the event is not firing! Please can someone advise how I can get the LoginButton_Click event to fire

Thanks

Comment: Does your form need to also be runat=server?

Comment: That's it..thank you! If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: pleasure. Been in the MVC world. Rusty on the old web forms, not to mention, classic ASP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form needs to be runat=server to be able to send the form back to the server and wire up the click event on the button.